# Is it mathematically correct to replace 1 with I?

Tags: matrices, determinant

For example,

> $3=3I$
>
> $=3\begin{bmatrix}
>         1   & 0 \\
>     0       &1  \\
> \end{bmatrix}$
>
> $=\begin{bmatrix}
>         3   & 0 \\
>     0       &3  \\
> \end{bmatrix}$
>
> and $\begin{vmatrix}
> 3 & 0 \\ 
> 0 & 3 \\
> \end{vmatrix}=9$

Does this mean $3=9$ ? Am I confusing determinant with "value of matrix"?

Comment: Do not confuse the determinant with the multiplication by a scalar!

Comment: It is mathematical correct if and only if $1$ and $I$ stand for the same mathematical object. Draw your conclusion.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that a matrix is the same thing as the determinant of the matrix, which is not correct.  For example, the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is $1$, but certainly the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ itself is not equal to the number $1$.

Comment: To the down voters,I know it is not a great question.I am just asking where am I wrong.It is not a h/w type question and I asked it for my own conceptual clarification.The thing is that:I am asking,not claiming.Are such questions against the policies of MathSE?Please vote to delete if it is.

Comment: @ItachíUchiha, to me it appears as if you already knew that this was wrong before you posted. If you read Wikipedia pages on matrices and determinats you will know that a matrix can't be equal to its determinant or any other scalar unless it's $1 \times 1$ matrix, i.e. a number. So, the question appears senseless to me, and which is why I'm tempted to downvote (but I won't do it). Also, with $4$ answers, it's impossible to delete your question at this stage

Comment: Okay.I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *know already that you're working with linear transformations of a particular vector space* (which form an associative algebra over the scalar field), then it is customary to write simply $3$ for the transformation that multiplies every vector by $3$, which is the same as $3I$.

So *if that is your context*, then $3$ and $3I$ is the same thing. That doesn't mean that the matrix $3I$ is the same as *the number three*, just that the symbol "$3$" is sometimes used to denote that matrix in addition to the number.

But the real problem in your calculation is where you apparently conclude from $|3I|=9$ that $3I=9$.

A matrix **is not equal to its determinant** -- you're getting those determinant bars out of nowhere, and you have no right to assume that $A=|A|$ even in a context where you use bare numbers as shorthand for certain matrices.

If it's given that you're working in the algebra of linear transformations of $\mathbb R^2$, then the best the various abbreviations will let you conclude is
$$ \det(3) = 9 $$
which looks strange but is not the kind of contradiction that $3=9$ is.

Comment: I'd say, if $r \in \mathbb{R}$, and $A$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, it is customary to write $r$ instead of *the image of $r$ under the natural unital ring homomorphism $\varepsilon: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A$*.

Comment: @lisyarus: Yes, that's what's going on under the hood here. But I'm trying not to confuse the OP too much, since he probably don't know about algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing 1 by I is a delicate thing.

$I$, the $n\times n$ identity matrix, enjoys many properties similar to the unit element in ${\mathbb R}$. If $A$ is any $n\times n$ matrix then $AI=IA=A$ and if $p(t)=p_0+ p_1 t + \cdots + p_d t^d$ is a (usual) polynomial, it makes sense to consider $p(A)= p_0 I + p_1 A + \cdots + p_d A^d$ as a matrix valued polynomial. 
If, e.g. $p(t)=\det(A-t I)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ then the (non-trivial)  Hamilton-Cayley theorem tells us that $p(A)=0$ (the zero matrix on the RHS).

But alas, 1 and I live in different spaces so they are not equal, so your calculation does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a $n\times n$-matrix and $t$ a real number, we have

$$\det(tA)=t^n\cdot A$$

So, in fact, you confused the determinant with a multiplication by a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

For any scalar $\;k\;$ and any $\;n\times n\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ , we have that

$$|kA|=\det (kA)=k^n\det A=k^n|A|$$

so in the example you wrote in your question:

$$|3I_2|=3^2|I_2|=9\cdot1=9$$

and yes: you were confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

No it is usually not correct to replace $3$ by $3I$. The former is the number $3$, while the latter is a matrix of some (possibly unspecified) dimension with $3$ on the diagonal. This is not the same object (except possibly if the dimension happens to be one, but this is a bit of a degenerate case).

There is some kind of an 'exception' to this though, which may be the cause of your questions:

Given a polynomial, say $p(x)= x^2 + 2x + 3$, one has that for a matrix $A$,  $$p(A)= A^2 + 2A + 3 I.$$ 
Thus here it seems that $3$ is replaced by $3I$. Yet, the confusion should  go away when one recalls that   $p(x)= x^2 + 2x + 3$ is short for $p(x)= x^2 + 2x^1 + 3x^0$, and $A^0 = I$.

Answer (score 0):

The rule  in the case of a constant (k) in one row is

$\left|\begin{matrix}
        a_{11}   & a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n} \\
    \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\ \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{s1}   & \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{s2}&\ldots& \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{sn}\\  \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\ a_{m1}   & a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{matrix}\right|=\color{red}{k}\cdot \left|\begin{matrix}
        a_{11}   & a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n} \\
    \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\  a_{s1}   &  a_{s2}&\ldots& a_{sn}\\  \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\ a_{m1}   & a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{matrix}\right|$

Or similarly: The rule  in the case of a constant (k) in one column is

$\left|\begin{matrix}
        a_{11}   & \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n} \\
    \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\  a_{s1}   &  \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{s2}&\ldots& a_{sn}\\  \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\ a_{m1}   & \color{red}{k}\cdot a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{matrix}\right|=\color{red}{k}\cdot \left|\begin{matrix}
        a_{11}   & a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n} \\
    \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\  a_{s1}   &  a_{s2}&\ldots& a_{sn}\\  \vdots      &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\ a_{m1}   & a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{matrix}\right|$

---

If you have $p$ rows/columns (distinct cases) with a costant ($k$) then the determinant has to be multiplied by k raised to power $p$.

You have $p=2$ rows (or columns) with the factor $k=3$. Therefore

$|A|=3^2\cdot |I|$